# Seifert Matrices and Seifert Surfaces for the following two Brunnian links

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory

Please consider the following two Brunnian links

[image]

my questions are:

1) How to compute the Seifert Matrices for such brunnian links

2) How to obtain pictures for the corresponding Seifert surfaces.

Answer (score 3):

In order to obtain the corresponding Seifert surface, we will use the program SeifertView.  We introduce the corresponding braid according with the code

```
AbCbACbCbAbAcb
```

The corresponding braid has the form

[image]

The output generated by SeifertView is the following Seifert surface

[image]

The smoothed and refined Seifert surface is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"To obtain a Seifert matrix for an $n$-component Brunnian link $L$, we shall use a Seifert surface constructed by the above “algorithm”..., see page $3$ [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0601726.pdf) for the construction.

Answer (score 2):

According with a previous post [Are the following two links isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251381/are-isomorphic-the-following-two-links?rq=1), the two brunnian links were identified as the link L14n63195.

Using the following code for SnapPy

```
L=Link('L14n63195')
word = L.braid_word(); word
```

the corresponding braid was computed and the output was

```
[1, -2, 3, -2, 1, 3, -2, 3, -2, 1, -2, 1, -3, -2]
```

Now using Sage with the following code

```
B = BraidGroup(4)
L = Link(B([1, -2, 3, -2, 1, 3, -2, 3, -2, 1, -2, 1, -3, -2]))
L.seifert_matrix()
```

the Seifert matrix was computed and the result was

```
[-1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  1  1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0 -1  1  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0]
[ 1  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0  1  0  0]
[ 0  0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0 -1  1  1 -1  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 -1]
[ 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 -1 -1  1]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  1]
```

[image]
Do you agree?