# An example of a hyperbolic Brunnian link with four components

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory

The brunnian link with four components  L14n63195 ([What link is this brunnian link?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127506/what-link-is-this-brunnian-link?rq=1)) is not hyperbolic.

Can you give me an example of a hyperbolic Brunnian link with four components?

Comment: [Hyperbolic links with Brunnian properties](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1230395010) sounds promising. Also [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119291/hyperbolic-brunnian-links-and-rectangular-cusp-shapes).

Answer (score 0):

A possible example is the link L12a1976
[image]