Brunnian links with 12 crossings and 3 components
It is well know that the link L12a1882 is brunnian.
I am looking for other brunnian links with 12 crossings  and three components.
I am conjecturing that the link L12a1896 is brunnian.
Could you please confirm it?
There is another example?
Many tnanks

An image of the link would be wonderful for the community. (Please provide some content, the known link mention is easily found on the wiki page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L10a140_link#Pseudo-symmetric_visual_variants, and from the picture it is a visual test to see that yellow goes over red, which goes over blue, which goes over yellow...)

trivially any two-component links with twelve crossings...

and this one perhaps, which I see is also a question of yours... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499342/an-example-of-a-hyperbolic-brunnian-link-with-four-components

@DrM  Many thanks for your answer.  I am looking for brunnian links with three components.  The link L12a1976 has four components.
