# Why the multivariate Alexander polynomial of L14n63195 is zero?

Tags: knot-theory

Using the Mathematica package "KnotTheory" I am obtaining that the Multivariate Alexander Polynomial for the link L14n63195 ([What link is this brunnian link?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127506/what-link-is-this-brunnian-link?noredirect=1&lq=1)) is equal to zero. Do you know what is the reason for this fact?

Many thanks.

Comment: The Wolfram article on [Alexander polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlexanderPolynomial.html) reads "The Alexander polynomial of a [splittable link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SplittableLink.html) is always $0$."

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin The given link is not splittable, so that wouldn't apply here.

Comment: I'm getting that its Alexander polynomial is $(t-1)^6$, so the multivariable Alexander polynomial shouldn't be $0$.  Are you sure you have the correct diagram?  I'll post two PD codes for you, generated using https://kmill.github.io/knotfolio/

Comment: PD[X[22,14,21,9], X[12,4,11,5], X[8,21,7,20], X[27,6,26,7], X[2,22,1,15], X[23,3,28,2], X[10,1,9,8], X[4,17,3,16], X[14,28,13,27], X[16,23,15,24], X[6,18,5,19], X[20,26,19,25], X[11,24,10,25], X[18,13,17,12]]

Comment: PD[X[5,25,4,28], X[20,1,19,12], X[2,13,1,14], X[12,16,11,15], X[7,13,6,18], X[18,23,17,24], X[9,16,8,17], X[22,2,21,3], X[19,7,24,8], X[10,27,9,28], X[15,21,14,20], X[23,6,22,5], X[27,10,26,11], X[26,4,25,3]]

Comment: @KyleMiller your PD codes are correct but KnotTheory says that the multivariable Alexander polynomial is 0.  I will try with Sage.

Comment: @KyleMiller, using Sage I am obtaining again that the Alexander polynomial is 0.  Please check it.