# What would be Conway and Rolfsen style notations for four-component Brunnian link?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

What would be Conway and Rolfsen style notation for the four-component Brunnian link given below:

[image: he four-component Brunnian Link]

It was also asked about the link here: [an old related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127506/what-link-is-this-brunnian-link)

Comment: According to an answer in that related question, the Rolfsen-style notation is L14n63195, meaning that it is a 14-crossing non-alternating link, and in the list it is number 63195 of that type.  (This link has $9^*$ as its basic polyhedron, and I'm able to work out the remaining details of the Conway notation in case it would be helpful.)

Comment: Thank you Kyle it will be helpful. If you have time plese write down the Conway notation. I am not so good in knots yet.